# Lifetime of QObject returned by QDjangoModel::foreignKey?

Tags: c++, qt, django-models, qdjango

In a class derived from QDjangoModel, I'm seeing code like this:

```
return qobject_cast<RawType*>(foreignKey(name));
```

I'm very experienced with C++, but completely new to Qt. I understand that the QObject returned by the `foreignKey` function acts like a smart pointer itself, but it can't know about how long the `RawType*` extracted from it will be used, so how can I tell its lifetime? What is holding the QObject in existence -- is it the QDjangoModel object?

(I did not write this code, obviously, and it may very well be a really bad design. They hired me to clean up this program's code, among other things.)

Comment: Having no idea what `QDjangoModel` is, maybe `QObject::destroyed()` signal could tell you when it (QObject) is going to die?

Comment: It's apparently a database-interface thing.

Comment: @vahancho see this documentation page for [QDjangoModel](http://doc.qdjango.org/qdjango-snapshot/classQDjangoModel.html): "[tag:QDjango] is a web framework written in C++ and built on top of the [tag:Qt] library (versions 4 or 5).Where possible it tries to follow [tag:django]'s API, hence its name." If OP provides more information it would also be easier to help.

Comment: I put in everything I could think of. What kind of additional information would help?